# Download a complete feedburner feed with Python

Tags: python, rss, feedburner

How can I download all posts from a feed such as http://feeds2.feedburner.com/meinscheissleben with Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did that go wrong? What research have you done into the subject and what did you find but not yet understand?

Comment: I'm quite new to Python, so I haven't tried anything specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [feedparser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser/) and read the [docs](http://packages.python.org/feedparser/).

```
   import feedparser
>>> url = 'http://feeds2.feedburner.com/meinscheissleben '
>>> d = feedparser.parse(url)

len(d['entries']) # nr of entries
d['entries'][0] # pick one
```